# getlogin() not working on Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL)

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux

It seems, that the `getlogin()` function is not working when called from the Linux subsystem on Windows (it always returns null).

This leads to two questions:

- Is there a working alternative?
- Is it possible to determine if we are on a "normal" Linux or a "Windows Linux" like stated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8249232/9699530)?

Comment: It's not a system call. It relies on a login, specifically a utmp record, I guess your WSL is not bothering to set that up when you open a WSL window. getlogin is probably working correctly, it's just telling you there is no utmp record :-P.  If you want some alternative, you need to explain exactly what behaviour you want.

Comment: @sourcejedi You're right. Somewhere else, I read that this utmp record doesn't exist (which seems to produce some more problems). I just need an easy way to display the username of the user who started the process.

Comment: good start. Is it a set-uid process, or does it run with the same UID as the process that exec()'d it ?  Do you want `sudo my-program` to show `root` ?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are still running as the same user: [getuid()](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/getuid.2.html) then resolve it to a user name.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39157675/how-to-get-linux-user-id-by-user-name